# Using Curl in PHP on my Http://localhost server workings fine, but using Curl on Http(s)://localhost will not output any CSS

Tags: php, css, curl

I am using Curl on  server to curl www.yelp.com, but using Curl on Http(s)://localhost will not output any CSS htmls sheets. I have tried:

CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE

But the issue is not curling the page, it is the fact that my browser Chrome does not seem to recognize any sort of CSS formatting. Any ideas?

For example, running the below code from http://localhost gives a well formatted page. Running the below code from https://localhost gives a page without css.

```
<?php
$url="http://www.yelp.com/";
$ch  = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64; rv:17.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/17.0"); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1); 
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,10);
$cl = curl_exec($ch);
echo $cl;

exit;
```

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you're asking. What does Chrome have to do with this? Do you have a server running on localhost with SSL enabled? What exactly is the problem you're running into?

Comment: Are you trying to proxy Yelp or something?

Comment: My server running on localhost has SSL enabled, so I am running my https://localhost. However, when I curl a page such as www.yelp.com and output it in my own browser chrome (echo $cl) I do not see any sort of CSS styling. I am not using a proxy. @EdCottrell

Comment: Well, if you are just retrieving the HTML and outputting that without any processing, you probably have tons of broken links, including relative paths to CSS and JavaScript files. There's your problem.

Comment: I have updated the code, running it from "http"://localhost and "https"://localhost gives two different results. @EdCottrell